# How to copy large files via network to multiple Linux PC at once?

Tags: linux, file-copy, multicast

I have 15 Linux PC and I need to install two virtual machine(Windows 10 and Ubuntu) in every one of these PCs.

I decided to install these two machine in one PC and copy virtual machine files to another PCs.

**I'm looking for a way to copy these file over network to all these PCs at one.**

I have ssh server enable in each one of these PCs(with same username and password) and in my case security doesn't matter.

I have a 100 Mb network so I prefer to find a way to do this with multicast instead of uni-cast.

Comment: You seem to be all set up, what are you missing? Although I very much doubt it will speed things up, you can just run the scp or rsync jobs in the background in parallel. What else do you need?

Comment: I need some automate way to copy all files without writing scp command for individual PC. and as I said I'm looking for something that use multicast not uni-cast because my switch have 24 fast Ethernet port so it take very long time to copy all the files maybe 20 GB with unicast.

Comment: Although I haven't tried it myself, it sounds like you want to use `uftp` or `mrsync`.

Comment: You can use torrent to distribute the files to your local network. Or create empty VMs and then boot them to `clonezilla` with the multicast option. Note that even if you do not run scp commands for each host, you will have to run something at each host.

Comment: @Zeta thanks. yes `uftp` and `mrsync` use multicast and probably I use these tools.
@EduardoTrápani, I used clonezilla before but there was a lot of error about clone that I was taken from a Ubuntu 20.04 in drbl version although I using this clone with normal clonezilla version and restore these clone to my PCs. But `torrent` was very interesting. and I know I have to do some thing for each PC but can i use something like `ansible` to automate this task?

Comment: @AmirSabeghi Ansible sounds like an overkill if you only need to do this once. I'd use `for host in $HOSTS; do ssh $host $REMOTECMD $REMOTEARGS > "$host.log" &; done` to start the remote processes and then run the appropriate command on the source. That being said, I still haven't tested `uft` or `mrsync`, otherwise I would provide an answer with a complete example/setup :(. By the way, Torrent is again P2P, but the peers can share already downloaded parts with other peers.

Comment: @Zeta Thanks again for your comments. I'm not sure that it's the only task that I want to be automated on my PCs so I decided to learn ansible. There is a lot of way to do this like `netcat` and `scp` that I used before but I was looking for a fast and easy way with least interaction from me.